# The eigenvalue multiplicity of a linear combination of two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are two infinite stochastic matrices (the sum of each row is unity) where the multiplicity of $1$ as their eigenvalue is $1$ (we know that $1$ is an eigenvalue for stochastic matrices). Now I make another matrix of the form $C=\alpha A+(1-\alpha) B$ where $0<\alpha<1$. Obviously, $C$ is another infinite stochastic matrix. But can we say anything about the multiplicity of eigenvalue $1$? Is it still one?

I just know that if they are finite matrices, then the multiplicity of $1$ is one. But here they are infinite!